# How can capture many images using picamera and loop and different name?

Tags: pi-2, raspicam, python-3

Here's my current Python code:

```
import picamera
with picamera.piCamera() as camera:
    for i in range (10):
        camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/newfile/newimage.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is tell the camera to capture to a file with the number `i` in its filename like this:

```
for i in range (10):
    camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/newfile/" + i + ".jpg")
```

Your corrected code looks like this:

```
import picamera
with picamera.piCamera() as camera:
    for i in range (10):
        camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/newfile/" + i + ".jpg")
```